# Why does go standard library prefer pointer receivers?

Tags: pointers, go

Is there a reason why Go standard library prefers pointer receivers, even where value receivers would work?

For example, in [go 1.14 io.multiwriter](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/96745b980cfde139e8611772e2bc0c59a8e6cdf7/src/io/multi.go#L54):

```golang
type multiWriter struct {
    writers []Writer
}

func (t *multiWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
...
}

...
func MultiWriter(writers ...Writer) Writer {
...
   return &multiWriter{allWriters}
}
```

This would work even if instead of `&multiWriter{allWriters}`, the function returned `multiWriter` value, and `func (t *multiWriter) Write` had a value receiver.

Is there a reason why go standard library consistently prefers pointer receivers?

Comment: In this case, I'd say it makes more sense to use pointer receivers because methods of the `Writer` interface imply mutability of the underlying object. Even if it doesn't entirely make sense in this particular example, (internal) consistency itself is often an argument, too

Comment: You've shown one example, and extrapolated from it that the "go standard library consistently prefers pointer receivers". The standard library generally uses pointers and values appropriately; for example, in the [`time` package](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) uses values for some types and pointers for other as needed; same for the [`net` package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/), to give just two examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiWriter`'s methods could indeed skip the pointer receivers, but since `MultiWriter` returns an interface and interfaces in Go only contain a [type and a pointer to the data](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces), you would need to separately allocate a struct anyway.

One interesting point here is that, as far as I can tell, this is an implementation detail and not part of [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types). One could imagine an alternative Go implementation which uses a different representation of interfaces in memory, potentially allowing small structs to fit directly in interface values without pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reason why go standard library consistently prefers pointer receivers

No.

Sometimes it's for compatibility reasons (e.g. because the first version would not have worked on value receivers). Sometimes it's for consistency reasons. Sometimes it's author preference. There is not much to see or learn here.